# SPFX webpart not added to site after deployment

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp, app-catalog

I have developed a SPFx WebPart using react.  When packaging this solution, I use the following commands:

```
gulp clean
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

FYI, I'm using these options in my package-solution.json file:

```
"skipFeatureDeployment": true,
"includeClientSideAssets": true,
"isDomainIsolated": true,
```

*It's worth noting, I've tried both with tenant deployment (skipFeatureDeployment = true/false) and without, same issue.*

This successfully creates my .sppkg file.  No errors.

I then upload the package to my SharePoint sites App Catalog in SharePoint Online (365), successfully, with no errors, then choose deploy, in this case to all sites:

[image]

The app is enabled, valid, deployed and tenant deployed:

[image]

The app does **NOT** show up in my site contents.  The app does **NOT** show up in "My apps" for the site.  The app does **NOT** show up in the WebPart picker of a page.  If I create a simple helloworld app scaffolded from yo, it works as expected.

So there is something about this app it does NOT like.  Where can I track down the logs or other data that would indicate why this app is failing silently and giving me no visual indication there is a problem during deployment?  It may also be worth noting that this app **WAS** working last week when I first deployed it.  However, I deleted the app from the catalog  and re-deployed several times testing different settings.  Now I can't get it to show at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some sort of AppCatalog caching/file remnant conflict related to removing/adding the app from the AppCatalog.  After speaking directly with Microsoft support, the only solution we found was to delete the app (again), then change the guid id in the package-solution.json file, then re-upload and deploy.  It began showing up again after that.

Without changing the Id of the package, no amount of re-uploading the app would allow it to show up.